# What does the Jacobian of a vector field at an equilibrium tell you about local behavior of integral curves when the Jacobian is not a stable?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, singularity-theory

I have a soft question regarding the Jacobian of vector fields and isolated equilibria, and what they imply about local behavior of nearby integral curves near.

Let $V:U \subset_{open} \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth vector field. Let $x^* \in U$ be an isolated equilibrium of $V$. That is, $V(x^*)=0$ and there is a neighborhood of $x^*$ with no other equilibria. It is well known if the Jacobian matrix, $DV(x^*)$, has eigenvalues with negative real part (i.e. Hurwitz stable), then $x^*$ is asymptotically stable.

In my research, I am dealing with a vector field with a single equilibrium, $x^*$, where $DV(x^*)$ has 1 simple zero eigenvalue and the remaining eigenvalues have strictly negative real part. I've noted numerically that $x^*$ is asymptotically stable despite $DV(x^*)$ not being Hurwitz stable (In fact, I've noticed it is globally asymptotically stable, but that is outside the scope of my question).

I have long term goal to show $x^*$ is asymptotically stable. For now, I need to learn what the Jacobian implies about the local behavior of an equilibrium point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Jacobian alone doesn't have the information you need. For example, consider the two vector fields
$$f(x, y) = (-x^2, -y)$$
and
$$g(x, y) = (-x^3, -y)$$.

They have an isolated equilibrium at the origin, with the same Jacobian: $\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$.

But the equilibrium in $f$ isn't stable, while in $g$ it is.

With the Jacobian you describe, you'd need some other information, like the existence of a Lyapunov function, to prove stability.

Comment: Doesn't center manifold theorems give us information about the local behavior?

Comment: In your case there exists a 1-dimensional center manifold (don't assume uniqueness, though!) through the equilibrium, and in a neighborhood of the equilibrium trajectories will be attracted to this 1D manifold. The issue is that the dynamics on the center manifold could be attracting, repelling, or (as in the first vector field above) a combination.